# Append to variable not working when passing += assign variables from command line to make

Tags: makefile

I am trying to append value to variable already has assign value from inside of makefile from cmdline but it doesn't working and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

In my Makefile:

```
FPP+=ONE
FOO+=TWO

target:
     echo "Value: $(FOO)"
```

If I run: `make`

it displays:

> Value: ONE TWO

But if I run: `make FOO+=THREE`

I was expecting:

> Value: ONE TWO THREE

But instead of I am getting:

> Value: THREE

So cmdline `FOO+=THREE` is override `FOO` instead of append.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Variables set on the command line cannot be modified by ordinary assignments within the makefile. You must use the [override directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive):

```
override FOO+=ONE
override FOO+=TWO
```

Comment: That work.  Thanks.